# How to code sign in Xcode for a development team?

Tags: xcode, code-signing

When developing a macOS application we usually sign the final product in the company's release process. However, as Xcode is pressing to code sign in every upgrade, I want to enable code sign also in the normal development process. However, the developers in my team have no access to the code sign certificate used to sign the app during release.

So I enabled automatic code signing using a personal team with my Apple ID, which works fine. However, how do I share that with my team mates, of which one doesn't even have an Apple ID? They cannot use my private account for that.

By accident I found that specifying "-" for the `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` setting in .pbxproj file uses AdHoc signing. However, that is not available in the Signing Certificate drop down in Xcode and must be added manually by editing that file. Seems a bit like a hack to me therefore. Any better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you all part of a company development team? If not, then find out who the team agent or administrators are and ask one of them to add you. You or one of the admins should be able to create a development certificate that you can use to sign development versions of the app. Only the released version needs to be signed with the release certificate.

Comment: Sounds good, but wouldn't that cause trouble for people trying to compile our (open source) app? They will first have to fix the code sign settings, right?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn’t seem like a big deal. If you think people won’t know how to solve that, put a note in the README file.